# “lumX” can live with internet explorer 8+?

Tags: internet-explorer, lumx

Which versions of IE can be used with lumX? I tried it in IE 9 and its not worked for me.

Its my error.

```
[object Error]{description: "Access is d...", message: "Access is d...", name: "Error", number: -2147024891}
```

Answer (score 0):

As LumX home page says

> Made with the latest technologies

While not explicit, I suppose IE versions that are HTML5 compliant will be able to support LumX. Though the HTML5 working draft specification began with IE8 and was extended in IE9. IE10 supported even more of HTML5 so this version is your best bet for full support next to IE11.